# Limit the number of ranges worked in a day

Tags: c#, or-tools

I'm writing code to automatically generate shifts for my workers.
There are several constraints I've already been able to create:

- Each shift in a day is assigned to a single worker
- Each worker can't work more than 8h per day
- Each worker should work [*#minShifts*, *#maxShifts*] hours per week
- Each worker can't work on different rooms at the same moment
- Each worker can't work on more than 2 different rooms in a day

So far so good; now I'm facing another constraint I can't really think how to code: *each worker can't work on more than 2 different ranges in a day*.
What I mean is I don't want a person to work (e.g.) 08.30-10.30, 12.30-13.30 and 16.30-18.30, but limit assigned ranges at two.

Given that I have `shifts[numWorkers, numDays, numShifts]`, how can I arrange this constraint?

Comment: So a shift always consists of  1|2 ranges (broken shifts?) and limited to 1|2 rooms? Is a range limited to 1 room?

Comment: @CasparKleijne: a shift is 1h and in a single room I can have 10 shifts per day. I consider a *range* when multiple shifts in a single room are joined, not broken. I'd like a worker not to have more than two broken ranges in a day. Hope it's clear, but please ask me if it's not! Thank you

Comment: I think there are just 28 permutations  regarding the amount of hours/shifts and ranges + 8 for non broken days (1 range a day), gives us 36 , is it possible to just add those?

Comment: @CasparKleijne: I think there are a lot more permutations: I have more than 15 workers, each range can be long from 1h to 8h and can spread along different times during the working day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stay with these variables for each block of two hours [8AM shift, 9AM shift], 
create a boolvar that is true is the first shift is ON and the second is OFF

```
end_of_shift = model.NewBoolVar('')
model.AddBoolOr([first_shift.Not(), second_shift, end_of_shift])
model.AddImplication(end_of_shift, first_shift)
model.AddImplication(end_of_shift, second_shift.Not())

# then for each day and each worker: 
model.Add(sum(end_of_shifts) <= 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Laurent, I knew there should be a way, but I didn't study your tool so deeply, shame on me!. :)

Comment: Coming back after a long time. The part you helped me was not working every single time... sometimes it worked, other times no. Finally I realized what was wrong: if you have a shift during the day and another shift at the end, the last one didn't have a `end_of_shift`, so it was not considered and I ended up having an additional and uncounted range.
To overcome this problem I added a fake shift always empty at the end and now everything is perfect! Thank you so much again :)